# show exact Grid design in collection view if data is not availble

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image: I want show collection view like this way if there is no data available. I have took two cells for this. addcell and picture cell. how to show grid design in collectionview if data not available. I want show grid exact shown in picture.]

I want show Grid design as per below image. If there is no data available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an empty UICollectionViewCell that just displays the white background. In numberOfItemsInSection just pad the view out to display a few extra empty cells. Then when your data loads just set the numberOfItemsInSection to the correct number that reflects your data.

Answer (score 0):

I can surely recommend you this great library, https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet it will be work on behalf on you. And you can easily set a place holder either normal string or a attributed string or an image in place of `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

When you will have the data just reload your object and it will hide that placeholder thing.

Use:

```
self.tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self;
self.tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self;

- (UIImage *)imageForEmptyDataSet:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_placeholder"];
}
```

For more info and usage, please check out above link.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this**

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
      {
          int numberOfItem =0;

          numberOfItem = array.count+1;
          return numberOfItem;

       }


    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
     static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

     UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     if(indexPath.row==array.count)
      {
           //////////load upload image with top icon hidden
       }
    else{
           /////////load your image with top icon unhidden
         }
  return cell;
      }
```